# Re-installed LyX and can't compile an Hebrew document

Tags: windows, hebrew, lyx

I'm using windows 7 and recently downloaded and installed LyX and MiKiTeX to my computer in addition to Culmus Hebrew  fonts for LyX.

However, when I want to compile a Hebrew Article it gives me an error:

```
 \begin{document}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
```

Can't fix it for months now.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I had this problem today. I downloaded older version (2.1.1) from http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/Windows and magically it worked

Comment: @Shlomi Did you mean version 2.0.8? Because 2.1.1 is the one giving me the trouble.

Comment: no I meant 2.1.1 but try 2.0.8. I think I used that before